# Social Engine restore admin

Tags: sql, socialengine

I'm running a site using Social Engine 4.2.6. The only Admin account was hacked & password was changed by someone.
How do I add a new Admin through Database ? I tried the normal methods of creating a new user in 'users' table with Admin Level, however the particular user can only access Members Area.

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the `level_id` field value to **1** to be super admin.

I've tried with one user on my site and that user can access the admin area. This works with basic socialengine 4.2.6 and original modules, not third party ones.